# having trouble adding types to this component ( new to typescript )

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im making a small todo app in react to get a taste of typescript.
my Todo class is just going to be used for Data entity and it consists of a todo label, complete status, and a key;

```
interface TodoProps {
  complete: string;
  label: string;
  key: string;
}
class Todo extends Component<TodoProps, any> {
  constructor(label) {
    this.label = label;
    this.complete = false;
    this.key = Date.now();
  }
}
```

My code editor keeps complaining that this.label, this.complete, and this.key
*does not exist on type "Todo"*
any ideas? thanks

Answer (score -1):

So in order to access the props on your component, you need to use the `props` getter:

```
 constructor(props: TodoProps) {
    super(props);
    this.props.label = props.label;
    this.props.complete = false;
    this.label.key = Date.now();
  }
```

What I wonder is if you intend to hard code both `complete` and `key` then why are they part of props?

why do you allow someone to pass `<Todo complete={true} />` if complete gets set to false immediately on construction?

Also, it has been a while since I used class components, but isn't the whole point of this line:

```
super(props)
```

to set your props object to be equal to `this.props`??

Comment: Like i said this is intended to be used as a data entity; its important that when working with this data, that it carries the expected props.

Comment: setTodos(new Todo('take out the trash')),  here is a use case for this data entity

Comment: I managed to find an answer. thanks though!